# Combining rows in dataframe based on partial duplication

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe df in which some rows contain identical values, but one does not.

```
V1    V2    V3
a     b     c
a     b     d
1     2     3
1     2     4
```

I'd like to remove those rows which contain the same values for df$V1 and df$V2, and then combine the values in V3 using ";;" as a separator like so:

```
V1    V2    V3
a     b     c;;d
1     2     3;;4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution based in the tidyverse could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  mutate(V3 = if_else(n() > 1, str_c(V3, collapse = ';;'), V3[1])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct()

#   V1    V2    V3   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 a     b     c;;d 
# 2 1     2     3;;4
```

**df**

```
structure(list(V1 = c("a", "a", "1", "1"), V2 = c("b", "b", "2", 
"2"), V3 = c("c", "d", "3", "4")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *aggregate* function for this purpose and pass *paste* as the aggregate function:

```
aggregate(V3~V1+V2, df, FUN=function(x){paste(x, collapse=';;')})
```

The temporary function definition is necessary to specify the *collapse* parameter as your special choice `;;`.